# Error 503 with WCF service

Tags: wcf, http.sys

I've got a self-hosted WCF service listening on port 80. When I attempt to connect to it, I get a `503 Service Unavailable`.

My WCF process is running, IIS is running. My URL ACLs are correct. Control never reaches my WCF process.

WCF tracing shows nothing more than:

```
Listen at 'http://localhost/Foo/Bar/'.
```

Nothing is shown in *Failed Request Tracing*, which is turned on correctly -- other tracing appears. The `503 Service Unavailable` message is resolutely plain, implying that it's coming from kernel mode, rather than user mode.

I've [turned on HTTP.SYS tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2007/01/18/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-1-capturing-a-trace.aspx), which shows that the namespace is reserved correctly:

```
Attempted to add URL (http://localhost:80/Foo/Bar/) to URL
group (0xFD0000014000002E). Status: 0x0.
```

But later, in the same trace, I see:

```
Request (request ID 0xF600000580000006) rejected
due to reason: UrlGroupLookupFailed.
```

I've tried `iisreset` a couple of times, but it doesn't help. I've also rebooted the PC; same problem.

What is going wrong? What else can I do to further debug this problem?

### Updates

If I rename the URL (changing "Foo" to "Fizz", for example), then it works. Looks like corrupted configuration somewhere.

I have other services hosted in the same process that are bound to `https://localhost/Foo/Bar/`, and they appear to be working correctly.

### It's not just WCF

I've had the same problem with a self-hosted **Nancy** service, and one of the commenters, below, reports the same thing with a self-hosted **ServiceStack** service.

Comment: Can you post your WCF service config? Also are you able to browse to the service from IE after you have your service running. If possible your code on how you are self hosting the service

Comment: I can't easily -- right now -- post much more. The WCF service config is unchanged since it last worked on this PC. Same with the code. It also works on other PCs. If I browse to it from IE, I get the same 503 Service Unavailable.

Comment: Can you try to delete your asp.net Temp files and then try at times these files dont get deleted and cause such issues.

Comment: No they don't. This is nothing to do with ASP.NET. But I did it anyway. No change.

Comment: Hmmm. Left it over the weekend (no reboots); working fine this morning.

Answer (score 12):

Had the problem again. Poked around with URL ACLs. There were a couple of URL ACLs that could be considered to be ambiguous.

I had `http://+:80/Foo/`, `http://+:80/Foo/Bar/` and `http://localhost:80/Foo/Bar/`. I deleted all except the 'localhost' one, and it started working.

Whether it was because of the ambiguity, or because deleting the extras caused something to be reset, I don't know...

Comment: I had the same problem with a self-hosted ServiceStack service. I used `netsh http show urlacl` to list the URL reservations, and then used `netsh http delete urlacl` to delete the ambiguous URLs leaving only the localhost one.

Comment: And I've just had the same problem with a self-hosted Nancy service.